# How do I apply the proposition of the form P->Q->R to two hypotheses P and Q simultaneously in Coq?

Tags: coq

I tried to prove `forall P Q R : Prop, P -> Q -> (P -> Q -> R) -> R`. My proof is the following.

```
Goal forall P Q R : Prop, P -> Q -> (P -> Q -> R) -> R.
Proof.
  intros P Q R H1 H2 H3.
  apply H3 in H1.
  exact H1.
  exact H2.
Qed.
```

When apply H3 in H1, two goals will appear. However, I want to obtain R more directly like `apply H3 in H1 and H2`.  But I couldn't find such a way.  How do I achieve this?

I already know that the following is also fine. But this is not what I want. I don't want to increase goals.

```
Goal forall P Q R : Prop, P -> Q -> (P -> Q -> R) -> R.
Proof.
  intros P Q R H1 H2 H3.
  apply H3.
  exact H1.
  exact H2.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply `H1` and `H2` to `H3` yourself directly, without using the `apply` tactic.

Your `H3` is of type `P -> Q -> R` (a function that takes proofs of `P` and `Q` and returns a proof of `R`). So, the expression `H3 H1 H2` has type `R`.

With this you can simplify your proof to the following:

```
Goal forall P Q R : Prop, P -> Q -> (P -> Q -> R) -> R.
Proof.
  intros P Q R H1 H2 H3.
  apply (H3 H1 H2).
Qed.
```

In fact, your proof is exactly the same as the one above because all the `apply` tactic does is applying a function to an argument.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!!